# Can't find the `BlockingQueueAgent` type within current F# assemblies?

Tags: .net, asynchronous, f#

Documentation on the web seems to point to this type being within FSharp.Control namespace & inside FSharp.Core assembly BUT I can't seem to find it there.

The type is a queue wrapper around a `MailboxProcessor` type.

I am using VS2015.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install the nuget package FSharpx.Async

```
PM> Install-Package FSharpx.Async
```

Homepage at http://fsprojects.github.io/FSharpx.Async/

Then you need to open the namespace FSharpx.Control.